# In RHEV-M/oVirt, how do I find the VM associated with a particular MAC-address

Tags: ovirt

I'm trying to use the manager to find a VM associated with a particular MAC-address. I'm using the search-bar in the WUI. The RHEV-M guide and oVirt CLI examples get me only so far. In the search bar, I try `VMS: vnic.network_name = X*` and I get all VMs with an interface in any of the X... networks. But I want to search on the mac address. Tried the obvious, (`mac`, `mac-address`, `mac_address`) but no go. For comparison, I tried "00*" which definitely should have gotten hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vms: Vnic = 00:11:22:33:44:55` is what you're looking for

Comment: I have verified it on RHEV 3.5, by copy/pasting the MAC of one of the VMs, using the exact syntax I provided. It worked just fine, returning the only VM that had that MAC. Actually, if you open a new question, describing the use case and what are you trying to achieve in the long run, maybe MACs will not be relevant, and I'll be able to provide a better solution overall

Comment: Some time after my post, we upgraded to 3.5.3. I tried it again and it worked. tyvm.

Comment: If you can answer this as well, I'd be grateful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383095/in-rhev-m-ovirt-how-do-i-find-a-list-of-searchable-attributes-properties

Answer (score 1):

Login to the engine postgres

Run this:

```
engine=# SELECT vm_name,mac_addr from vm_interface_view where mac_addr='00:16:3e:74:8e:ad';
```