# In RHEV-M/oVirt, how do I find a list of searchable attributes / properties?

Tags: ovirt

I cannot find any documentation pertaining to the list of searchable properties of objects (VMs, Hosts, etc) within oVirt / RHEV-M? There is no documentation on this, either in RHEV or oVirt sites (via Google). Can someone provide a list of such attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty much self evident, you can simply connect to the SDK with ipython and tab your way through the available options. Of course this doesn't mean better documentation shouldn't be created, I suggest you open a red hat bugzilla request for that.

Comment: LOL, I'm sorry. The code is anything but "self evident". There are three different layers and I have no idea which layer I should be looking for, nor in what kind of file to look for them. Is Java using some kind of reflection class to determine the properties? If so, no hope. If it's some kind of enumerated class, like you would do in C, I have been unable to find it.

Further, I cannot connect to our infastructure via the SDK because our admins have restricted it for some reason. I just need a list.

Comment: I didn't mean the actual engine code, I mean the SDK. I usually connect to it using ipython and tab through my options - they are very easy to manipulate and are self evident. There are some quirks of course, but once you get confortable with this way of work, you will never look at the CLI again, and might skip using the GUI even